# i18next/react: Trans displaying "undefined" in element

Tags: reactjs, jsx, i18next

I'm getting my bearing with i18next, but `Trans` is offering me riddles when I try to work with a link. Everything is working well with t{} so far (I'm working in React – JSX):

Here is the code that almost works (other approaches I tried didn't work at all):

```
<p className="button"><Trans i18nkey="home.p3" components={{ MyLink: <a href='beispiele.html'>link</a> }}/>{t('home.p3')}</p>
```

JSON:
de:

```
{
 (…)
    "home": {
       (…)
        "p3": "Durchstöbern Sie unsere <5>Beispiele</5>.",
     (…)

    }
}
```

en:

```
{
    (…)
    "home": {
        (…)
        "p3": "View <MyLink>samples</MyLink> of our work.",
       (…)
    }
}
```

and this is how I initialize i18next:

```
i18next
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
.init({
  debug: true,
  fallbackLng: 'de',                              // language to use
  resources: {
      en: {
          translation: common_en               // 'translation' is our custom namespace
      },
      de: {
          translation: common_de
      },
  },
});
```

The resulting text displayed: undefinedView samples of our work.

I've looked at the i18next documentation on using `Trans`, also trying to use <1></1> and similar to encapsulate the link. Each time "undefined" is displayed. I've gone through [this tutorial](https://locize.com/blog/react-i18next/), where it worked. And have been mirroring it as closely as possible. The `Trans`element is not being grasped, although there are no error messages.

I'd appreciate any tips on how I can further troubleshoot this. Many thanks!

---

ETA:
thanks to Ahmet's eagle eye one mistake has been found. I'm not correcting it above, in case someone else runs into this problem: it should be `i18nKey`.

Further digging showed I have to place the JSON files in to the public folder to have the links work. For those looking into this: use `i18next-http-backend` in your init (i18n.use(Backend)) in your setup so you can reach the folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in your `Trans` component. You need to change the `i18nkey` prop to `i18nKey`.

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i18next-displaying-undefined) for a live working example.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I was staring at it for too long to see it, I'm sure. I also noticed that you have an extra parenthesis around the link. However, I'm still not quite there yet. I see that it works for you, but I'm getting "home.p3" as the output now … For some reason it is not replacing the key with the value.

Comment: These extra parentheses are auto-generated when I format the code, they do not affect the jsx.

Comment: That's interesting. I get a different output with and without. Without: "home.p3View <MyLink>samples</MyLink> of our work." – With "home.p3". It seems like there is some other detail getting in the way, especially seeing it works in your sample code …

Comment: Well, at least I'm getting an error now: "i18next::translator: missingKey de translation home.p3". And it only happens with `Trans`, when using t{} it finds it. I'll update the original question to reflect this.